# How to integrate dataProvider approach in selenium WebDriver keyword driver framework

Tags: java, selenium, testing, keyword, dataprovider

I am developing keyword driven framework in selenium(webdriver) java using testing.
I have a function library class where i kept/stored all the methods which needs to perform on websites/webapplications for testing i.e. **enterValues** in input boxes, **click** button/level, **select** dropdown etc. 
We invoke all these methods from my Driverscript/DriverEngine which reads TestSuite(.xlsx) excel file(Using POI API) where all testcases are documented. 
TestSuite excel file having specific format i.e. 
In first sheet, TestSuite where all test cases documented using their run mode ‘Y’ or ’N’.
From (second)next sheet onwards, each sheet is named as similar to test case name(in test suite sheet) and its test steps. 
Test case format in Testsuite.xlsx file is i.e. our column name is

Teststep==Description==Keywords==Object==ProceedonfailFlag==Testdata

their respective values are as shown below…

01==enterusername==enterValue==UserNameInputBox==Y==USERNAME(which user takes from TestData.xlsx file).

Now, till here, it is working great…

In my application, there is a functionality to add multiple user-dependent inventory/objects into the application form. These objects are random based on User's requirement. 
This feature is achievable by @dataProvider class implementation using TestNG. We are able to run such usecases (same operation multiple times) by creating TestNG dataProvider class separately. 
But we fail to achieve it by integrating in Keyword file(mentioned earlier). We want to a call this function like other methods from Keyword file. I am totally blank on this approach.Please suggest me, how to integrate the dataProvider approach in KeyWord framework and call this as a action/keyword/methods in java from and in excel file.

More, enhancements,

My framework is purely keyword based. My Testsuites are documented in first sheet of excel file(with run mode) and test cases started from sheet-2. A Driverscript reads excel file using poi api. Driver Script checks the keywords in excel (as enterValues in textbox and clickButton methods) and invoke the same methods from Keyword java file.Till here, there is no issue.                   My Testcases are executing in sequential ways i.e. TC1-Lauch browser with desired URL. TC2: Create Quote Object by providing information i.e name,dob,sex etc and verify the result generated based on the user data.     Now,third Testcase is TC3: Add multiple dependent of user to the next form as Enrolment form. Multiple dependent have common characteristics like dob,gender etc which we have to add manually. I can automate the Third test with DataProveder concept. My TestData excel file have mandatory fields as header in excel i.e. name,initial,dob,gender,relationship(wife,child,parents etc.) etc. etc. and One have file where i had applied testNG data provider 2 dimensional arrays of excel data.This I can execute separately as a standalone test but I want to know, how to integrate this test in my Keyword framework to run all the tests in a single shot. Please help me out to resolve this. I does not have very deep conceptual knowledge of this topic. so please provide solution in understandable format.Thanks, Vivek

I am Thankfull to you in Advance.
 BestRegards,
Vivek

Comment: First of all without the dataprovider business, you are using the keyword framework to drive selenium and using testng just for assertion purposes. With the dataprovider stuff, then testng becomes the driver for selenium bypassing your keyword framework. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes...Thanks and I am sorry if i was not able to explain it clearly. My framework is purely keyword based. My Testsuites are documented in first sheet of excel file(with run mode) and test cases started from sheet-2. A Driverscript reads excel file using poi api. Driver Script checks the keywords in excel (as enterValues in textbox and clickButton methods) and invoke the same methods from Keyword java file.Till here, there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first sheet where you have the names of test cases add two more columns. One which will have 'Y' for multiple data test case. Second one will be the name of the excel file which contains the data ie the excel that currently dataprovider is using.
2. Using your example go to the TC3 sheet in your excel workbook. Reusing the original header you have mentioned and adding to it.

   01==enterusername==enterValue==UserNameInputBox==Y==USERNAME
   02==enterdob==enterValue==DOBInputBox==Y==DOB
   03==enterCreator==enterValue==CreatorInputBox==Y==Vishal
   ...
   ...

Change this to mention the column from where the data needs to be picked up such as B and so on from your current dataprovider execl

```
01==enterusername==enterValue==UserNameInputBox==Y==$$ColB$$
02==enterdob==enterValue==DOBInputBox==Y==$$ColC$$
03==enterCreator==enterValue==CreatorInputBox==Y==Vishal
...
...
```

So now you have mapped the value of username, dob etc mapped to the column of the TC3 data excel. If you check step 3 you can put in values that are constant across all TC3 multiple entries. I have used $$$$ symbols to differentiate between normal data and column mapping data.

3. Now you need to modify the script that runs your keywords. If you come across a test case with multiple set to 'Y' you need to now pick up the name of the data excel from the next column. Parse in the data from the data excel sheet in a collection or whatever apache poi returns.
4. Create a 'for loop' or 'while' using the size of collection to limit it. Now what you have is for each iteration of the loop you have test data for one running of TC3. Now you just need to map input data for username, dob etc etc to the values in the test data. Send them to the keyword methods and it should execute for all the data one by one.
5. Do make sure in your test cases using multiple data that you always make sure your tests run properly in case of errors. That is if they error out they should come back to the correct screen for the next set of data.

You can avoid all you have done and going to do by having a look at Cucumber tool which is open source. It is an out of the box solution which integrates with Selenium, plus any other DI container you want to use.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks Sir.Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome... If it works for you can you accept this answer.